# Removing duplicate records for the same date in BQ table

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to remove duplicate records from a BQ table where each team contains duplicate records for the same date. I want to keep the most recent date and delete the remaining two records. Here is an example shown in the image. I would like to remove two entries with time stamp 2021-06-04 10:26:34.762000 and 2021-06-04 10:26:34.762000 but keep the most recent one with timestamp
2021-06-04 16:39:04.428000

```
teamId  jiraboardId createddate                 backlogstorycount   backlogbugcount backlogchorecount   backlogtotalcount   lastupdateduser lastupdateddate                 UUID                                    storyPoint      bugPoint    chorePoint  totalPoint  
1       150     2021-06-04 10:26:34.762000 UTC  16                      0               1               17                  Xcelerate       2021-06-04 10:26:34.762000 UTC  57926a8e-32a3-4ba0-832f-df62bde18b4a    52              0           3   55  
1       150     2021-06-04 16:23:51.029000 UTC  16                      0               1               17                  Xcelerate       2021-06-04 16:23:51.029000 UTC  07075027-6f53-4089-8a15-66dfe45d8250    52              0           3   55  
1       150     2021-06-04 16:39:04.428000 UTC  16                      0               1               17                  Xcelerate       2021-06-04 16:39:04.428000 UTC  7b5be9ef-2a24-4c9f-846b-2a203a63e734    52              0           3   55
```

Tried to comeup with the below query but didn't work as expected

```
delete 
 FROM `aaa.bb.jira_backlog` bl 
 LEFT JOIN 
  ( SELECT MAX(`createddate`) as createddate,backlogstorycount,backlogbugcount,backlogchorecount,backlogtotalcount,
    storyPoint,bugPoint,chorePoint,totalPoint FROM `aaa.bb.jira_backlog` b
    GROUP BY backlogstorycount,backlogbugcount,backlogchorecount,backlogtotalcount,
    storyPoint,bugPoint,chorePoint,totalPoint
  ) A
    ON bl.createddate = A.createddate
   AND bl.backlogstorycount = A.backlogstorycount
   AND bl.backlogbugcount = A.backlogbugcount
   AND bl.backlogchorecount = A.backlogchorecount
   AND bl.backlogtotalcount = A.backlogtotalcount
   AND bl.storyPoint = A.storyPoint 
   AND bl.bugPoint = A.bugPoint 
   AND bl.chorePoint = A.chorePoint  
   AND bl.totalPoint = A.totalPoint 
 WHERE A.createddate IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hey I can't see the image I attached. Can anyone see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your approach:

1. you have different metadata like different uuids in your records so just making MAX(createdate) is not going to help you.
2. You are trying to delete more records than to keep, this may affect your time performance as I do not see any partition/clustering info on the table.
3. More size of the table, the more time it will take you to delete.

To get an entire row as is which is based on some id and timestamp as a differentiator, you would need some kind of window/numbering function like row_number or rank.
[Ref: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions#rank]

Here is a sample:

```
select *, rank() over (partition by some_id order by ticket_timestamp desc) as rnk from (
select '1' as some_id, current_timestamp() as ticket_timestamp, 'metadata1' as metadata
union all 
select '1' as some_id, timestamp_sub(current_timestamp(), INTERVAL 10 HOUR) as ticket_timestamp, 'metadata1.2' as metadata
union all 
select '1' as some_id, timestamp_sub(current_timestamp(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR) as ticket_timestamp, 'metadata1.3' as metadata
union all 
select '2' as some_id, timestamp_sub(current_timestamp(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR) as ticket_timestamp, 'metadata2' as metadata
)
```

[image]

Now, you can see you have 2 ticket info in here, with 2 different ids and its timestamps and with different metadata now you have to choose only rnk = 1 to "keep" the records and rest needs to be skipped.

so you can do something like:

```
select * except(rnk) from (
select *, rank() over (partition by some_id order by ticket_timestamp desc) as rnk from (
select '1' as some_id, current_timestamp() as ticket_timestamp, 'metadata1' as metadata
union all 
select '1' as some_id, timestamp_sub(current_timestamp(), INTERVAL 10 HOUR) as ticket_timestamp, 'metadata1.2' as metadata
union all 
select '1' as some_id, timestamp_sub(current_timestamp(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR) as ticket_timestamp, 'metadata1.3' as metadata
union all 
select '2' as some_id, timestamp_sub(current_timestamp(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR) as ticket_timestamp, 'metadata2' as metadata
)
)
where rnk = 1
```

This will give you only 2 rows of output that has the latest timestamped with the correct entire latest rows of metadata as well.

(As for the delete/keep approach it's up to you, but one quick suggestion:
you can get new incoming data and go through the above logic and find only records to keep and append to your final table. )